# Whenever tableau sends a data driven alert, I want to trigger an external API call

Tags: aws-lambda, tableau-api, amazon-sns

I am using Tableau Servers data driven alerts. Whenever our alerts threshold is passed, we send an email to users. However, I also want to call an external API from my application (not in tableau).

I have considered trying to use AWS SNS to trigger a lambda but was hoping to see if anyone else has faced a similar use case? It does not seem like Tableaus Rest APIs provide enough metadata to handle this use case for data driven alerts

Comment: Tableau has a relatively new feature called web hooks. I’m not sure whether that would support your use case or not, but it’s worth checking out. Let us know.

Comment: Ya I had seen those, but the issue is how to capture that a data driven alert event has been fired. If I can access that event then I can use web hooks to call the api I think

Comment: This may be a dead end, but before Tableau supported data driven alerts, there was a open source approach called VizAlerts - I think available on Tableau's GitHub page. I'm not sure if that will be useful, or show any ideas, but worth a quick look.